# It's possible to recover a deleted pg_hba.conf linux postgresql file?

Tags: postgresql, linux

If anyone delete the pg_hba.conf file, and don't run "pg_ctl reload", the configuration of the deleted file is still working.
With that in mind, could someone put in a new file that info wherever it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 10, then this is possible through the view  [pg_hba_file_rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html)

For earlier versions, I am not aware of any way to retrieve that.